# How to utilize After The Deadline Extension in Libre Office Writer 5.1?

Tags: libreoffice

I'm currently using Ubuntu 16 and it has built-in Libre Office 5.1. In the first place, I'd encountered a problem about locating synonyms per word and I managed to solve it. The second problem is grammar checker, I tried to find a solution for it and found out that I have to use extension like *After The Deadline, Language Tool*, and etc. I chose the after the deadline and successfully installed it however, I don't have an idea how to utilize it.

Please help me. Thanks.